# Update text file from a POST route - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `text file In tab delimited format` which I am reading and it is returning me an array of objects from an `express get route`

```
[
    { MEMBER: 'ANY TYPE OF DATA', STATUS: 'PROCESSING' },
    { MEMBER: 'ANY TYPE OF DATA', STATUS: 'PROCESSING' },
    { MEMBER: 'ANY TYPE OF DATA', STATUS: 'PROCESSING' }
]
```

I want to make changes to this data and on save I want to update the data in the file again.

Lets say I modify the above data-structure to:

```
[
    { MEMBER: 'I MODIFY THIS', STATUS: 'PROCESSING' },
    { MEMBER: 'ANY TYPE OF DATA', STATUS: 'PROCESSING' },
    { MEMBER: 'ANY TYPE OF DATA', STATUS: 'PROCESSING' }
]
```

How can I use the `nodejs file system` and update the text file with the updated data in an `express post route`.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried/where you're stuck? Writing above structure that you get from the request back into a file shouldn't be a problem or am I missing something here?

Comment: @eol yes.......